# The jupyter kernel dies while using np.array to convert a list to numpy array for large list 15000*512*512

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I have made a list of size 15000*512*512 successfully. But while converting it to numpy array the kernel dies

```
The kernel for Desktop/RESERCH/V3.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

The code I was running is

```
train_img = []
Y = []
for itr in tqdm(range(len(labels))):
    # adding the orignal image
    train_img.append(images[itr,:,:])
    Y.append(labels[itr])

    # rotating the image by 45 degrees
    train_img.append(rotate(images[itr,:,:], angle=45, mode = 'wrap'))
    Y.append(labels[itr])

    # flipped around x-axis
    train_img.append(cv2.rotate(images[itr,:,:], cv2.ROTATE_180))
    Y.append(labels[itr])

    #flipped around y-axis
    train_img.append(np.fliplr(images[itr,:,:]))
    Y.append(labels[itr])

    #adding salt noise to the image
    train_img.append(SaltNoise(images[itr,:,:]))
    Y.append(labels[itr])
train_img = np.array(train_img)
```

I do not think this is happening due to the memory issue because I can create the list with no problem

Comment: problem is that the system needs twice the memory to be able to copy the old data into the new one. You have to use only the np.array structure.

Comment: allocate the proper number of rows in the numpy array first and change the elements